# Model Release with 3-way collaboration involving LLC

Tags: contract-law, photography

I will be facilitating photoshoots through my LLC and was wondering if anyone has any recommendations around contracting / due diligence.

I'll be working with a photographer and a model. They will be doing the shoot and providing photos to me for me to distribute on my channels with my branding (and theirs, if they desire). I don't mind not owning copyright, but I do want distribution rights. I don't know much about the legalese here. No money is being exchanged yet - but in the future one or more parties may be paid.

All parties are open to anything - I just want to make sure I've done everything properly and professionally. Hopefully without dumping capital on a lawyer.

Has anyone ever shot with this structure before? Any advice on documentation I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worrying about "dumping capital on a lawyer" is like worrying about dumping capital on fire insurance. Good legal advice at the formation of a contract is insurance against litigation - a few hundred pounds now in order to save tens of thousands latter.

That said, the basic requirements of a contract are not hard: [What is a contract and what is required for them to be valid?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/what-is-a-contract-and-what-is-required-for-them-to-be-valid)

Be careful with consideration, as there is no money changing hands you need to be clear what of value each party is bringing to the deal. Also, copyright belongs to the photographer barring anything to the contrary: are you going to transfer it to yourself or use it under licence. If a licence, will it be exclusive? For what period? Under what conditions?

Agree, write it all down, make 3 copies, everyone signs all 3, keep one each.