# Is it legal to ask users to pay for exporting their data?

Tags: privacy, data-ownership

I have a RescueTime account (rescuetime.com) and I want to export all of my data with its API. However based on my experimentation the API can access data of only three most recent months.

If I want to access reports of last year on the website, I need to pay for a subscription. I believe the API for raw data export has similar restrictions. Is it legal to charge me for my own data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RescueTime Lite has a 3 month report history limit. You agreed to the [RescueTime TOS Terms of Service](https://www.rescuetime.com/tos) when you signed up, and that included the stipulation that you only get 3 months of data with the free plan. That's clearly on the subscription page:

[image]

That's legal. They can charge you for access to more than 3 months of data in the form of a longer subscription. You're not being asked to pay to access your data; you agreed to a free plan that included limited access to that data.

And this is part of what [you "signed"](https://www.rescuetime.com/tos) as a click-wrap contract that is relevant to your dispute:

> ...You understand and agree that the cancellation of your membership or a
>   particular component of the Service is your sole right and remedy with
>   respect to any dispute with RescueTime. This includes, but is not
>   limited to, any dispute related to or arising out of: (a) any term of
>   the TOS or RescueTime’s enforcement or application of the TOS; (b) any
>   policy or practice of RescueTime, including the Privacy Policy, or
>   RescueTime’s enforcement or application of these policies; (c) the
>   data available through the Service; (d) your ability to access and use
>   the Service; or (e) the amount or type of fees, surcharges, applicable
>   taxes, and any RescueTime billing methods. RescueTime, in its sole
>   discretion, may terminate your membership and remove and discard any
>   of your Recommendations without notice if RescueTime believes that you
>   have violated or acted inconsistently with the TOS. RescueTime will
>   not be liable to you for termination of your membership to the
>   Service....

You only recourse in a dispute with them is to stop using the service. (Also see [Are terms of service legal contracts?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/13549/are-terms-of-service-legal-contracts/13571#13571) )

And RescueTime retains all rights to your data. It might be the data that you contributed to the service, but you granted them a permanent license to use it.

> The license granted in these TOS does not constitute a transfer or
>   sale of RescueTime’s ownership rights in the RescueTime Database.
>   RescueTime retains all right, title, and interest in and to the
>   RescueTime Database including all related intellectual property
>   rights.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Europe's General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) the answer to your question generally now seems to be "No, it is not legal to ask users to pay for exporting their data". Specifically, [Article 15 grants users (or what the GDPR calls "data subjects") a right to access their personal data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation#Information_and_access):

> A data controller must provide, upon request, an overview of the categories of data that are being processed (Article 15(1)(b)) as well as a copy of the actual data (Article 15(3)

and they must do so in a useful way:

> In addition, the data must be provided by the controller in a structured and commonly used standard electronic format. The right to data portability is provided by Article 20 of the GDPR

With regards to RescueTime specifically: while they still [charge for access to their sorted, filtered, and aggregated report data through the dashboard](https://help.rescuetime.com/article/96-premium-reports#exporting), they now allow anyone with an account to download a copy of their full, raw logged time data every 30 days: https://www.rescuetime.com/accounts/your-data

They talk more about their compliance with the GDPR in a blog post: https://blog.rescuetime.com/personal-data-gdpr/