# Can I set a fee for using my web site, and later collect it?

Tags: united-states, internet, terms-of-service, debt, invoice

If I set terms of service for my web site, visitors to my web site agree to them when they use my web site (beyond, presumably, the usage technically required to obtain the text of the terms).

It is not unheard of for web sites to charge users to access them. *Usually* this is implemented as a paywall, where the site refuses to provide pages until the user makes a payment. But that creates friction on the customer journey, because the visitor has to bother with advance payment.

**Can I declare in my web site's terms of service that accessing my web site costs money, and then seek to collect from repeated visitors?** Is there some threshold of noticability that that term would need to reach to actually be binding, since it would be highly unusual?

If I somehow could identify a frequent visitor who hadn't paid, and sent an invoice, would I get in trouble for some kind of speculative invoicing crime?

Would I win a debt collection suit against them if they refused to pay the invoice?

Would I be able to compel an ISP to reveal the identity of a subscriber in order to collect a debt from them?

Comment: So you want to freely serve up content to folks for a while, then spring a bill on them? At the very least that will get widespread publicity and your website's name will be trashed far and wide.

Comment: @JonCuster the content is not free of charge.  It's like a restaurant: you ask for something and pay for it later.  The difference here, however, is that it's also something that people don't expect to pay for and aren't prominently notified of, such as a library that has a difficult-to-notice sign informing patrons that they'll be sent a bill for e.g. sitting in a chair at a rate of, say, $20 an hour.  I wonder what percentage of "I've read the terms of service" clicks are made by people who've actually read the terms of service.

Comment: @phoog - well, suppose I walk into a cafe, they give me a nice latte, and let me walk out without comment. I do that for a few weeks, thanking them for the latte. Then after a month they bill me for 25 lattes and threaten to sue. Regardless of the legal issues, that would not be a good PR move.

Comment: How would you bill them? You can obtain the visitor's IP address, but that is not their email address, and they might be using a VPN so it isn't their actual IP address either. *"Would I win a debt collection suit against them"* – against who?

Comment: @JonCuster I wouldn't dare walking out of the restaurant without explicitly asking whether I owe them something. Clearly, if they say something like "no, it's on the house" they can't send a bill later.

Comment: @WeatherVane One could require "free" registration first.

Comment: @PMF but OP says that registering creates friction. And even if you "register", who is the debt notice served to? There is nothing like paying up front, or providing a payment card that can be verified.

Comment: The notice that there is a fee doesn't have to be buried or hard to find. I could put a big yellow banner at the top: "This web site costs $20.00 per month to use, payable by invoice, as detailed in our terms of service <link>". And I would like to know if I could get an ISP to identify a user from an IP and time because they owe me money, or if I would only be able to collect from users who also gave me contact information at some point, or admitted to using the web site where I could see it.

Comment: I don't think an ISP will provide details of its subscribers just because you ask. Subscription services have been pretty well worked out: you pay for a login. With some they have a free usage allowance, for example Google Location Services API which used to be free to use, but now you have to provide payment details in advance, with a free usage threshold. One thing you could do, is to record IP addresses and if they make many visits without paying, deny them access.

Comment: ... sooner or later a visitor will have to pay you. Instead of "sending them an invoice" make a frequent visitor register and pay you online, or deny them access. You could give them a "countdown". Then you don't have the time and trouble of chasing a "debt".

Comment: Funny enough, this is how [PACER](https://pacer.uscourts.gov/), the Federal court records access system works. You open an account, and they send you a bill later. Part of it is due to public fairness reasons, if your charges are less than a threshold per quarter, the bill is waived.

Answer (score 1):

### If you have a contract, yes

See [What is a contract and what is required for them to be valid?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/what-is-a-contract-and-what-is-required-for-them-to-be-valid)

There are plenty of service contracts that are billed in arrears: electricity, phone, internet, haircuts etc. so there is no problem with this sort of contract in general. Pay-as-you-go cloud services, like Microsoft Azure, use exactly this model although the usages is typically automated rather than manual.

Providing your customer has been made aware of the terms and has accepted them, this should be fine. However, see [Are terms of service legal contracts?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/13549/are-terms-of-service-legal-contracts/13571#13571)

Answer (score 1):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

In England and Wales (and I believe in Scotland) you couldn't do this. The [Interfoto case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfoto_Picture_Library_Ltd_v_Stiletto_Visual_Programmes_Ltd) makes it very clear that hiding unusual or onerous conditions in the fine print so that you can spring them on the unsuspecting customer at a later date is not allowed.

More generally, in common law jurisdictions (including the UK and the USA) contract formation is a "meeting of minds"; the two parties must have a common idea of what the agreement entails. Written terms are merely there to memorialise the agreement. If the customer doesn't realise that they are incurring a cost then they haven't agreed to those terms, and the supposed "contract" cannot be enforced.