# How to tell if an agreement is a contract?

Tags: united-states, contract-law

Let's say someone has an agreement with me about X.

Under what conditions would this agreement be a legally binding and enforceable contract?

Every definition I find online says that it's a contract if it's "legally binding and enforceable", but that's utterly unhelpful and begs the question of what constitutes legal bind and enforceability.

Comment: Look up "elements of a contract".

Comment: Check out https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/what-is-a-contract-and-what-is-required-for-them-to-be-valid