# How can one prove that a contract was signed by force?

Tags: contract-law

I posted another question recently relating to the same person but I didn't want to include two questions in the same post.

My father is an extremely abusive person and has been physically, mentally, and emotionally abusive throughout my life. When I was in college, he came to my apartment and forced me to sign a "contract" in which I would be forced to pay him $30000. This contract was essentially me writing out "I promise to pay  $30000" with my signature at the bottom. I told him numerous times I did not want to sign anything without a lawyer present, and he threatened to hit me if I did not sign it. I even tried telling him I would sign it if it included that he never contact me after college, but he cornered me and raised his fist up in an attempt to punch me.

That was 2 years ago, and he still has the contract and threatens to use it if I don't listen to him. Is there any way I can prove to someone that I was essentially forced to sign this contract, assuming he did try to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not get anything from this "contract", and all it says is that you will pay someone a sum of money "on demand", it does not meet the [basic requirements to form a contract](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/), and in particular, there is no *consideration* being received by you. **It would therefore not be a contract and would have zero legal force**.

If you do receive consideration, demonstrating that you signed the contract *under duress* will require specific legal advice, and you need a practicing lawyer in your jurisdiction.

Comment: Would a contract lawyer suffice,

Comment: A lawyer specialising in contract will help with any contract-related issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can give sworn evidence about the event you described. Depending on the circumstances, you might do that orally in a court room, or in writing in a statement or affidavit. Whether your claim is 'proved' will depend on whether the facts are disputed, the standard of proof, your credibility (potentially including how you respond to cross-examination), and the existence and credibility of any inconsistent evidence.