# roofing contractor contingency agreement

Tags: contract-law

I have signed a contingency agreement with a roofing company here in Colorado. Am I bound to anything here? It seems like a 'good faith' agreement that I will contact my insurance company. If I don't follow up with the roofing company with a claim number, which is what they would need, am I in violation of anything?

The contingency agreement that states:

Insurance Allowance Agreement:
I/we agree to retain [roofing company] to contact my insurance company and meet with their representative (adjustor) as our Contractor of Choice to discuss the scope of necessary repairs. Upon our receipt of the insurance estimate we will meet with a representative of [roofing company] to review the paperwork and discuss the scope of the project.

By signing below, you agree to:

- (A) call your insurance company to obtain a claim number
- (B)
  authorize a representative of [roofing company] to meet with your
  insurance adjustor to discuss and review the required repairs as your
  contractor of choice.
- (C) meet with a representative of [roofing
  company] when your insurance paperwork arrives to discuss the
  production process.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

Its a [contract](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/what-is-a-contract-and-what-is-required-for-them-to-be-valid). You have to do the tings it says you have to do and they have to do the tings it says they have to do.