# Changing mind about agreement before taking effect

Tags: australia

If two parties A & B both agreed to sign off on a development program document on x date, where the development program document states the agreement will take effect on Y date, however A changes their mind and sends notification in writing to other party B stating they reject the program on date C, prior to/ before agreement takes effect on Y date

Does A have to continue to accept agreement or does it become null and void?

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our [tour page](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

### Agreements can be cancelled at any time, contracts can’t

If the agreement is a contract ([What is a contract and what is required for them to be valid?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/6263/344)), then it’s binding and failing to fulfil the obligations in it is a breach that can lead to a lawsuit. The innocent party is entitled to be put in the position they would have been in but for the breach. So if B expected a $5 million profit (or whatever) then A must make B whole by paying them $5 million (or whatever).

If the agreement is just an agreement then either party can cancel *unless* they are [estopped](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estoppel). Estoppel is a complex area of equity law which in this instance says if A made a promise and B relied on that promise to take or not take some action and A knows B is doing that and B will suffer loss if A breaks that promise then A can’t break their promise. More or less, as I said, estoppel is complicated.