# Roommate isnt paying her half of the utilities, can I sue her?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, rent, debt, bills

So my roommate, her kids, myself, my mother (who is visiting lt) and my dog live in a duplex and we each pay rent, separatly, to the landlord. The utilities are all in my name except the wifi; that's in her name and I don't have any access to. Since February she stopped paying.
Every month I send her a copy of the bill and the breakdown of her half. Every month.
She tells me she can't pay or she'll pay it soon, or ignore me. Do I have a case? Can I take her to court?

Comment: You're in the US. You can sue anyone for anything, as long as you pay filing fees! You might get dismissed by the court however.

Answer (score 0):

> Roommate isnt paying her half of the utilities, can I sue her?

Yes. The easiest, most economic option is to file a complaint in Small Claims Court, since the amount in dispute most likely is within the [limit](https://nycourts.gov/courthelp/smallClaims/index.shtml#:%7E:text=You%20can%20sue%20for%20up,in%20Town%20and%20Village%20Courts.&text=and%20Suffolk%20County-,This%20guide%20will%20tell%20you%20everything%20you%20need%20to%20know,judgment%2C%20find%20resources%20and%20more.) in the NY jurisdiction even if yours is a town/village court.

Other than that, be sure to read [my answer on a very similar matter](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/46862/18505). There you will find remarks that will help you preempt or defeat the roommates' possible allegations.