# Is there a contract to protect work on a revenue share project?

Tags: united-states

Revenue share format is a very popular method of working in the indie game development scene. This format is basically people forming a group and develop a game without any payment until a demo or the game itself is released. Usually this groups are not legally established as companies until the release of the game or if they get funds.

Is there any type of document that could be used to protect someone's work in this type of scenarios? For example, a document that is signed by everyone on the group that explicitly describes what the distribution of work, which could be used if it is needed later on as a proof in any legal scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any type of document that could be used to protect someone's
>   work in this type of scenarios?

#### Yes.

It's called a contract. You don't have to have a business to have a contract between people. This particular type of contact is commonly referred to as a partnership agreement.

You can contract for just about anything you want, as long as it's not illegal. Draw one up and have everyone sign.

Better yet, if you have something to lose - like money, IP, etc. - get a lawyer to draw up the contract so you don't find yourself losing out from your own mistakes if you have to litigate the contract.

See [What is a contract and what is required for them to be valid?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/what-is-a-contract-and-what-is-required-for-them-to-be-valid)