# Is there a legal / commercial term for a free offer that can't be demanded or expected

Tags: legal-terms

What is the name for a service offer that is limited in availability due to resources or which could be withdrawn if it is being abused or unreasonably expected?

Is there a standard legal or commercial term that covers this situation?

Something like:

- limited availability,
- pending resource availability...
- no obligation (generally refers to the recipient)

Comment: Reasons with downvotes are helpful.

Comment: Hi AnthonyVO, I am voting to close because this question is asking for legal advice. If you can, please edit the question to be more generic, e.g., remove "I".

Comment: Hi Anthony - it's doubtful there is a specific word or phrase that has been designated as "the term" for something like this.  The ones you provided sound fine.  "While supplies last" also comes to mind although it, as well as your first two, sound more applicable to an offer of a finite quantity of goods to first-comers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An [invitation to treat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invitation_to_treat)

If you make an offer then, if the person(s) you made the offer to accept it (as it is - any changes make it not an acceptance but a counter-offer) then you have a legally binding [contract](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/what-is-a-contract-and-what-is-required-for-them-to-be-valid). Once you have a contract, your options for terminating it are limited and, absent a breach by the other party, generally only in accordance with the terms of that contract.

Conversely, an invitation to treat is not an offer - it is a statement that you are willing to enter negotiations.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I just learnt something new, especially regarding that "Generally, advertisements are not offers but invitations to treat, so the person advertising is not compelled to sell."   Very helpful and spot on.  Adding a note about that to your answer would make it even better.

Answer (score 0):

It is called as an 'Invitation of Offer'.
It is a call for your customers to offer you giving them a discount on a prescribed minimum sale. It is upto you whether to accept or reject that offer each time.

Comment: Are 'Invitation of Offer' and 'Invitation to Treat' synonymous?  I chose the other answer because of the supporting link but I found other references using the term 'Invitation to Offer' and they seem to be used the same way.

Comment: Yes, they're both the same things. :)