# Do NDAs apply to all future interactions between the two parties or just the next one?

Tags: canada, non-disclosure, confidentiality

A follow up to the question [is an NDA binding for sex worker or escorts?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/89244/is-an-nda-binding-for-sex-workers-or-escorts)

If someone hired an escort (or sex worker) and had her sign an NDA stating that she will not divulge their relationship, and that the client had hired her as an escort, would such an NDA need to be signed before each encounter or just the first one? Basically I'm asking what is the perpetuity of when an NDA applies to confidential information. For example you normally sign an NDA once for an employer at the start, but I guess with an escort it might be considered separate encounters each time.

Comment: That would clearly depend on the exact text of the NDA. There could be “on any occasion before April 30th, 2023” in the NDA.

Comment: What if it doesn't specify one way or the other, like this one https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/606993/Example-One-Way-Non-Disclosure-Agreement.pdf

Comment: Your example has actually strong restrictions. The biggest one is that the nda stops when the information becomes public knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Depends on the NDA

Just like any other contract, it does what it says it does. You could draft the NDA either way.

Comment: What if it doesn't say one way or the other? For example it just says "the receiving party will not disclose confidential information" then gives a definition of confidential information. This is basically what I've seen in most NDAs.

Comment: Then it applies to all confidential information received whenever that happens